# MySql: Как установить инкремент в ON UPDATE поля?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Есть поле, которое считает кол-во кликов

Так я сейчас делаю с кода: `UPDATE table SET count = count + 1`. Задался вопросом, можно ли делать это автоматически, задав значение ON UPDATE (как с CURRENT_DATE и др.) при создании таблицы.

Comment: 1) почему не добавить в свой update count = count + 1;  2) напишите триггер на update

Comment: *можно ли делать это автоматически, задав значение ON UPDATE* Нет.